# Why does css behave so differently based on what tag I attach it to?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I get this result:

[image]

With the following HTML:

```
<ion-view view-title="{{ 'WELCOME' | translate }}">
  <ion-content class="padding cust-vertical-center">
    <form class="list">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" class="text-align-center" placeholder="{{ 'EMAIL' | translate }}" ng-model="credentials.email"  autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="password" class="text-align-center" placeholder="{{ 'PASSWORD' | translate }}" ng-model="credentials.password"  autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off">
      </label>
      <button class="button button-block button-stable" type="submit" ng-click="okLogin()">{{ 'LOGIN' | translate }}</button>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.cust-vertical-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  background: red;
}
```

If I move the `cust-vertical-center` class from the `<ion-content>` element to the `<form>` element or a `<div>` element that wraps the `<form>` element, I get the following very different appearance:

[image]

Why this huge difference in appearance? Why does it matter if I attach the css to `<ion-content>` or `<div>` or `<form>`? The CSS code looks very generic to me

Comment: The `left: 50%;  top: 50%;` is the reason for this huge difference.

Comment: Why does it affect ion-content and div/form differently?

Comment: I can't reproduce because I don't know ionic but mostly this is because `position:absolute`, change it to `position:relative` and see if it fixes it

Comment: That is because you have made their positions absolute, which then makes them independent of other elements.

Comment: Does an element with tag name `ion-content` actually appear in the resulting HTML? If so, what is the default (initial) CSS applied to this element?